# AVAudioPlayer not responding to stop command?

Tags: class, ios5, xcode4.2, avaudioplayer

I'm currently trying to use a custom class for the AVAudioPlayer and all works great for playing a audio file but when it comes to stoping the said file it just skips over the stop command and plays another on top of the current file,

If anyone has any ideas on why this is happening I'd really appreciate the help.

Below is my AudioPlayer1.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AudioPlayer1 : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

    AVAudioPlayer   *player;

    BOOL playing;
    NSTimeInterval duration;        
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) AVAudioPlayer *player;
@property(readonly, getter=isPlaying) BOOL playing;
@property (readonly) NSTimeInterval duration;


-(void)GetSoundFileDuration:(NSString *) sound_file_name;
-(void)play;
-(void)stop;

-(void)setVolume:(float) volume;

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag;
- (void)PlaySoundFile:(NSString *) sound_file_name;

- (void)notPlaying;

@end
```

Below is the contents of AudioPlayer1.m file:

```
#import "AudioPlayer1.h"

@implementation AudioPlayer1

@synthesize player;
@synthesize duration;
@synthesize playing;

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil)
{
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];
    [player initWithContentsOfURL:nil error:nil];
    player.delegate = self;
}
return self;
}

- (void) setVolume:(float)volume
{
[player setVolume:volume];
}

- (void)PlaySoundFile:(NSString *) sound_file_name
{
[player stop];
NSURL *sound_file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sound_file_name ofType:@"mp3"]];

[player initWithContentsOfURL:sound_file error:nil];
[player prepareToPlay];
playing = YES;
[sound_file release];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
NSLog(@"audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying");
playing = NO;
}


- (void) play
{
NSLog(@"Play Called");
[player setVolume:0.1];
[player play];
playing = YES;
}

- (void) stop
{
NSLog(@"Stop Called");
[player setVolume:0.0];
[player stop];
playing = NO;
}


-(void)GetSoundFileDuration:(NSString *) sound_file_name
{
NSLog(@"%@",duration);
}

-(void) notPlaying
{
playing = NO;
}

@end
```

And below is the code that would start the audio:

```
- (IBAction)WPNaritive01:(id)sender
{
AudioPlayer1 * player = [[AudioPlayer1 alloc] init ];

if (player.playing == YES) 
{
    [player stop];
}

if (player.playing == NO)
{
    [player PlaySoundFile:@"1"];
    [player setVolume:0.1];
    [player play];
}
}
```

I apologize about the odd layout to the code as I'm still learning. I've only now found out about making these classes by chance from reading another question. lol

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured it out.

Rather than creating the object over and over like I was perhaps doing in the code above I should have been alloc and init the player in viewdidload rather than doing it in the IBAction like I did.

This is what I did incase anyone else comes across the same problem:

LockonLocation.h

```
@interface LockOnLocation : UIViewController {

AudioPlayer1 *player;
...
```

LockonLocation.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
player = [[AudioPlayer1 alloc] init ];
...
```

And I used the same code as above to play the audio so that was correct.

If anyone has any other advice for me or any other members I'd love to hear from you...